# Installing test-helpers extension for PHP on Windows fails

Tags: php, windows, unit-testing, pear, pecl

Trying to install phpunit test-helpers ( https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-test-helpers )

```
C:\>pecl install phpunit/test_helpers
downloading test_helpers-1.1.0.tgz ...
Starting to download test_helpers-1.1.0.tgz (10,370 bytes)
.....done: 10,370 bytes
4 source files, building
WARNING: php_bin C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\php.exe appears to have a suffix \php5.3.8\php.exe, but config variable php_suffix does not match
ERROR: The DSP test_helpers.dsp does not exist.
```

Using "pecl config-set php_suffix .exe" did not change anything. Unfortunately no recent precompiled DLL's are available to try setting them up manually.

Comment: I used to have a hell of a time installing extensions on Windows. Once I switched to Linux instead it was amazing how easily/smoothly things worked. The problem is that as an open source project, PHP ends up having most of its windows support as a labor of love. As a result, the windows environment just isn't as well supported. Sorry I can't be of more help :/

Comment: Yup. The development and production servers are Linux, so there is no problem there. But my personal dev environment is set up on Windows (WAMP, PHPStorm, SQLYog, TortoiseSVN). You know how it is, one can be very attached to the dev environment and all the little tools one collects over the years :).

Comment: You're so right. I finally threw up my hands and went with a Linux desktop. With the available virtualization options you can hold on to all your windows stuff in a VM, though. **Don't ... take ... my ... Notepad++ ... argggh** *(I just died right there)*

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's an issue with the test-helpers distribution package.

See the issue and comments: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-test-helpers/issues/6#issuecomment-3654335

If anyone knows how to fix it, it would be great! :)

> **Note:** [the Test-Helper extension is superseded](https://twitter.com/s_bergmann/status/457816903881588736) by https://github.com/krakjoe/uopz